# How to get prediction interval given non normal data?

Tags: distributions, prediction, prediction-interval

I'll start by saying that I have very little background in statistics and that my question title above is probably worded incorrectly. If I need to change the title to more accurately reflect my problem, please let me know. So here's the problem....

Lets say I person fished in a lake 200 times. Each time he (or she) caught a fish, it was magically replaced by another so that the population of fish in the lake remained constant. The time it took to catch a fish each of the 200 times was recorded. A histogram of this data is shown in the link below. x axis is time in minutes and y axis is number of instances.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMOK3.jpg

Now if the person were to fish in the same lake just once more for some amount of time, say 50 minutes, whats the probability he or she will catch a fish?

I'm assuming its not as simple as taking the total number of times the person caught fish in under 50 minutes and dividing by the total number of times gone fishing, but maybe it is. I was doing some googling and I think I should be able to associate a probability with a prediction interval based off the 50 minutes. However, everything I could find on prediction intervals was for a normal distribution, which this data is not. My next thought was I could just reflect the data about the y-axis and would then have a decently nice normal distribution to work with but something tells me I can't just do something like that. Any help on this would be appreciated, thanks!